# How the UIActionSheet works?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

When popping a view I want to save some data, by asking confirmation. I'm asking confirmation using UIActionSheet. But irrespective of my response in action sheet, the view is changing in background, it creates some problem for me to use the response. I'm using navigation controller to switch views. How can I solve this

TIA

Comment: what do u mean the view is changing in the background ?

Comment: Can you post the code, so that it will be clear to understand

Comment: use uialertview for asking confirmation and on button's of alert(there is delegate when called once pressed in alert) save information u want

Comment: Have you checked the action @selector, of ur alertview ?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, You use uiactionsheet for user confirmation, while in background (actually under actionsheet) you change view controllers. Well, you can't do that, because delegate must be attached to controller which shows it up (if i am wrong, correct me). So when you click button, you can only first dismiss actionsheet and then change view controller, but not opposite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PooLas If I understood you correctly, You use uiactionsheet for user confirmation, while in background (actually under actionsheet) you change view controllers. Well, you can't do that, because delegate must be attached to controller which shows it up (if i am wrong, correct me). So when you click button, you can only first dismiss actionsheet and then change view controller, but not opposite – PooLaS

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to use uialertview for asking confirmation.To do this follow this step:

Insure your header file contains the following:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Now when asked confirmation add this code:

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Are You Sure" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"YES" otherButtonTitles:@"NO", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Now after pressing one button below delegate will be called so add in .m file of app

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
 // the user clicked one of the YES/NO buttons
  if (buttonIndex == 0)
  {
    NSLog(@"NO button pressed");
  }                
  else
  {
    //Save data here                                          
    NSLog(@"YES button pressed");
  }
 }
```